# The change of polygon contain make my demo wrong in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, projection, geo

I'm using **D3** to draw some pieces of information on canvas. And I got my aim in **version 3** but failed in **version 4** (Of course, I had changed the updated functions in version 4 such as `d3.geo.mercator()` to `d3.geoMercator()`). I debugged some relative functions and found the projection function was different.

In Version 3:

```
function projection(point) {
  point = projectRotate(point[0] * d3_radians, point[1] * d3_radians);
  return [ point[0] * k + δx, δy - point[1] * k ];
}
```

In Version 4:

```
function projection(point) {
  point = projectRotate(point[0] * radians, point[1] * radians);
  return [point[0] * k + dx, dy - point[1] * k];
}
```

My code Snippets is following:

```
var d3Projection = d3.geoMercator().scale(1).translate([0, 0]);
// var d3Projection = d3.geo.mercator().scale(1).translate([0, 0]);
var d3Path = d3.geoPath().projection(d3Projection);
// var d3Path = d3.geo.path().projection(d3Projection);
var pixelBounds = d3Path.bounds(features);
var pixelBoundsWidth = pixelBounds[1][0] - pixelBounds[0][0];
var pixelBoundsHeight = pixelBounds[1][1] - pixelBounds[0][1];
```

I debugged there and found **the value of 'δx' was different from 'dx'**, which is the same condition on **'δy(dy)'**

Debugging in Version 4
[image: Debugging in Version 4]
Debugging in Version 3
[image: Debugging in Version 3]

**Could you someone explain the differences in this condition, please?**

**And what's the meaning of dx(δx), dy(δy) ?**

D3 V3 [correct demo](http://www.sknight.cn:81/d3.v3-map.html).

D3 V4 The center coordinate is wrong. [wrong demo](http://www.sknight.cn:81/d3-map.html).

**_______________________________________________________________________________**
**I found the different code which result into my wrong demo**
[image]
This code was changed from v3.5.17, if I change this line code back to v3.5.16, everything will be OK. I will get the reason.

Comment: I found the ·d3.geoMercator().scale(1).translate([0, 0])· make wrong projection.
If I remove the translate([0,0])，my demo will work with the wrong center

Comment: It would be best if you could create minimal example, not the whole application. The projections between V3 and V4 should be identical, as can be seen from the source code, so I'd guess there is an error somewhere else. When I tried your snippets, just calculating the bounds of some featureset, it  returned the same array.

Comment: @veproza I had added the online Demo.The D3 V4 is wrong in center setting.  The snippet code I thought have problems in /components/wind/wind.js(wind-d3.v3.js), 'function name' is **getProjection**. I guess whether my topojson data is not standard.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I was able to get your demo running on my PC, but it would have been easier if you had a *minimal* demo, just enough code to get the error reproduced, not the whole application.

Answer (score -1):

The projection function in vanilla D3v3 and v4 is identical, your problem is that you're using some modified D3v3 version. If you try running this snippet in your D3v3 environment (assiming the topojson is loaded in `var topo`):

```
var features = topojson.feature(topo, topo.objects.counties);
var d3Projection = d3.geo.mercator().scale(1).translate([0, 0]);
var d3Path = d3.geo.path().projection(d3Projection);
console.log(JSON.stringify(d3Path.bounds(features)));
```

you'll get

`[[-3.141592653589793,-3.141592653589793],[3.141592653589793,3.141592653589793]]`

If however you load current `https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js`, the same exact snippet will produce

`[[2.110384445824674,-0.5558860193147427],[2.1337212032517625,-0.5298056661805025]]`

which is the same as V4. So you either need to fix your code to work with current D3 (v3 and v4), or modify your D3v4 in the same way as D3v3.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll check the 'modified D3V3'.

Comment: I found the D3 v3 code is same as my invoked, so it's not the reason of 'modified code'

Comment: Alright, try making a minimal example, not a whole app, we'll see if it gets us any further. It's way too complicated to navigate the whole app for anybody to effectively help you.

Comment: https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/issues/140, The URL of minimal examples are on the fourth floor. Thanks a lot that you persist in solving my problem!