# Set D3 projection in Openlayers 4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, openlayers-3, projection

[The Demo](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/d3.html?q=d3)

I confused on D3 Integration using Openlayers 4.

The confused code is following ：`var d3Projection = d3.geo.mercator().scale(1).translate([0, 0]);`

Why set the value of '**scale**' is '**1**' and the '**translate**' is '**[0, 0]**' when init the ***Mercator projection***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are set there so that the *bounds* of the features can be computed, and, followingly, the correct `scale` and `center` can be deduced.

Try putting an extra `console.log(scale, center)` into the `canvasFunction`, and then move the map, zoom it, or try emulating a high-DPI display (eg. in Chrome Developer Tools). You'll see how these values change with every pan and zoom.

The values `1` and `[0, 0]` are set to ease the computations, as defaults are  set so that the whole Earth map would be drawn by default (per [scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#projection_scale) and [translate](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#projection_translate) documentation). That's practical for when you're coding the function for the first time and want to see some sane results, but less useful when you need to compute the projected bounds.

Comment: Thanks for your patiently explain. However, I met another problem with D3 and OpenLayers. I will express my sincere thanks to you if you can help me.
This is url:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397496/d3-geo-projection-function-is-different-between-version-3-and-version-4